# Is there a way to tell if a string slice is in another string in Python?

Tags: python

I am working on a larger project but I've arrived at an issue where I am taking a slice from a string and I am attempting to tell if the slice is in a main string. The problem is that even though the types are the same it seems that the 'in' operator and 'index' operators don't work with the slice. Is there a way to tell if a slice is contained in a 'main string' or can you not compare slices and strings in that way? Here is some example code on what I am trying to accomplish:

```
x = ['dog']
value = 'dog'
y = 'All values with: ' + value
searchvalue = y[16:]
for i in x:
    if searchvalue in i:
        print('Is in')
    else:
        print('Not in')
```

So I want to be able to tell that the value 'dog' taken as a slice from 'y' is in 'x'. I fee like it should be simple but I've come to a dead end so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to find  `dog` instead of `dog`
Change searchvalue to this

```
searchvalue = y[17:]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is the index number. Use `17` or `searchvalue.strip()`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).